# Filter for noisy image with low contrast

Tags: image, opencv, image-preprocessing, halcon

I try to implement OCR in a really noisy image. There is also a low contrast between the number and background. I have tried to use some median filter to smooth background noise and edge enhancement method but without sensible effect. Does anyone have something similar task to do? What filter should I use?

Number with background's noise and low contrast:

[image: Number with background's noise and low contrast]

EDIT (ADDED OVEREXPOSED PICTURES)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the letters/digits always in the same font at the same size - or can you know it in advance?

Comment: They are in the same size. There are no letters, only numbers from 0-16.

Comment: Are you able to do the acquisition again or do you only have the images to work with?

Comment: Are the digits always in the same font?

Comment: The digits are always on the same font.

Comment: You may have better luck with template matching in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to do the image acquisition again there are few options:

1. Try to overexpose the image, which might have a positive effect on the segmentation of number from the background. I just wrote a post about it: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-overexposure-work-you-part-i-vladimir-perkovic
2. Since you have the Halcon tag, I assume you have access to Halcon. Take a look at example ocr_embossed_photometric_stereo.hdev which shows how to read embossed letter using lights from multiple directions.

In case that you have to work with only existing images the best I've got is using the Maximally Stable Extremal Regions (MSER) in Halcon:

```
rgb1_to_gray (Image, GrayImage)
segment_image_mser (GrayImage, MSERDark, MSERLight, 'dark', 600, 60000, 1, 'may_touch_border', 'false')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to overexpose the picture. I lost noise on the background but the digit's edges are not well visible. I have to take more pictures with different digits. 

I will also try also to use other lightning because now I have coaxial without a polarizer. I will use a bar light with a polarizer and a polarizer filter for the camera.

I never try to use photometric stereo - this would be also worth finding out but I have to use more light for that - I have HDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this shared images' resolutions are very low (nearly 190x160). If real images' resolutions are higher than this images, you can get better results. I tried some codes on images. I found digits as "6" and "&".

Screenshot is here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I1s79hwcon8IdxC6peRxMbaB4I2taNFr

Code is here:

```
dev_get_window (WindowHandle)
set_display_font (WindowHandle, 18, 'mono', 'true', 'false')

**reading image
read_image (Pnk9h, '/home/emin/Desktop/pNk9h.png')
get_image_size (Pnk9h, Width, Height)

**bluring image but preserve the edges
bilateral_filter (Pnk9h, Pnk9h, ImageBilateral, 9, 10, [], [])

**sharpening image
emphasize (ImageBilateral, ImageEmphasize, 7, 7, 5)

**processes about finding digits
var_threshold (ImageEmphasize, Region, 150, 150, 0.2, 2, 'dark')
var_threshold (ImageEmphasize, Region2, 150, 150, 0.2,5, 'light')
fill_up (Region, RegionFillUp)
difference (RegionFillUp, Region, RegionDifference)
opening_circle (RegionFillUp, RegionOpening, 3.5)
connection (RegionOpening, ConnectedRegions)
sort_region (ConnectedRegions, SortedRegions, 'first_point', 'true', 'column')
select_shape (SortedRegions, SelectedRegions, ['area','row','row1','row2'], 'and', [150,Height/2-20,10,0], [99999,Height/2+20,Height,Height-10])

smallest_rectangle1 (SelectedRegions, Row1, Column1, Row2, Column2)
gen_rectangle1 (Rectangle, Row1, Column1, Row2, Column2)
intersection (Rectangle, Region, RegionIntersection)
opening_circle (RegionIntersection, RegionOpening1, 2)
area_center (RegionOpening1, Area, Row, Column)
union1 (RegionOpening1, RegionUnion)

**painting image for reading robustly
paint_region (RegionUnion, ImageEmphasize, ImageResult, [0,0,0], 'fill')
complement (RegionUnion, RegionComplement)
paint_region (RegionComplement, ImageResult, ImageResult, [255,255,255], 'fill')

**reading digits
read_ocr_class_cnn ('Universal_0-9+_NoRej.occ', OCRHandle3)
do_ocr_multi_class_cnn (SelectedRegions, ImageResult, OCRHandle3, Class3, Confidence3)
dev_disp_text (Class3, 'image', Row2+10, Column2-50, 'blue', [], [])
```